# ¿Cómo deserializar una clase Java desde un fichero binario?

Tags: java

Hola soy nueva en todo esto de la persistencia por medio de la serialización de clases.

Mi problema es que tengo una clase que tiene un `String nombre`, y dos `ArrayList` que se llaman `horas` y `dias`.

Cuando inicio el programa lo primero que tiene que hacer es deserializar la clase y volver a cargarme los datos en las variables que mencioné anteriormente. Cuando llamo a `ObjectInputStream().readObject();` me retorna un objeto de la clase en cuestión pero no sé cómo volver a poner los datos en las variables.

Intenté por medio de getters y setters pero no funcionó.

```
 public void readObject(){

    DatosMat dm;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(temp);
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
            dm = (DatosMat) ois.readObject();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

y me gustaria que la variable nombre de DatosMat obtenga el valor de dm.setNombre()
Ahora, como tendria que ser setNombre() para que ocurriera eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola hice un codigo de ejemplo el cual tu clase debe parecer similar , codigo :

```
public class DatosMat implements Serializable
{
    private String nombre;
    private List<String> horas,dias;

    public DatosMat(String nombre, List<String> horas, List<String> dias) 
    {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.horas = horas;
        this.dias = dias;
    }

    public String getNombre() 
    {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) 
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public List<String> getHoras() 
    {
        return horas;
    }

    public void setHoras(List<String> horas) 
    {
        this.horas = horas;
    }

    public List<String> getDias() 
    {
        return dias;
    }

    public void setDias(List<String> dias) 
    {
        this.dias = dias;
    }

    private static void serializar(DatosMat datos,String rutaArchivo) throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(rutaArchivo);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject( datos );    
    }

    private static DatosMat deserializar(String rutaArchivo) throws  IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(rutaArchivo));
        return (DatosMat) in.readObject();
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        String rutaArchivo = "/home/charbel/Escritorio/weasasas.txt";
        DatosMat datos = new DatosMat("Charbel", Arrays.asList("12:30","15:25","13:20","10:45"), Arrays.asList("Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves"));
        serializar(datos, rutaArchivo);

        //Se procede a leer el Objeto al momento de deserializar
        DatosMat otrosDatos = deserializar(rutaArchivo);

        //obtenemos el nombre validando que se ha obtenido informacion del objeto
        System.out.println(otrosDatos.getNombre());

        System.out.println("dias");
        //he utilizado un foreach con expresiones lambdas ya que la version de Java JDK es la 8,en caso de ser una version menor de java se debe utilizar un ciclo for normal
        otrosDatos.getDias().forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("horas");
        //he utilizado un foreach con expresiones lambdas ya que la version de Java JDK es la 8,en caso de ser una version menor de java se debe utilizar un ciclo for normal
        otrosDatos.getHoras().forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```

Comment: Hola Jose, gracias por tomarte tu tiempo. Hice algo muy parecido a lo tuyo y cuando imprimia el nombre salia null, ahora intente hacerlo como lo hiciste vos y me sigue dando null. Alguna idea de que puede pasar?

Comment: te sirvio la respuesta ?

Comment: Ahi edite la anterior, habia apretado enter y se envio el comentario

Comment: puedes insertar tu codigo para revisar porque te da null, es una variable static ?

Comment: Ya encontre el error, estaba poniendo un constructor vacio en vez del que tiene los parametros a escribir. Gracias!

Comment: de nada, estamos para ayudar.